USB 3.5" HDD that uses USB-PD (no additional power supply)
I am searching for an external USB-C HDD 3.5" enclosure (for a single disk) that only requires one USB-C cable, no additional power supply.
USB-PD (Power Delivery) allows devices to query voltages higher than 5V, therefore it would be possible for an external USB HDD enclosure to request 12V and use it to power the HDD without  the need of an additional 12V power supply. Of course that would mean that the case can only work if the USB host port supports USB-PD with and 12V.
Such a case would be helpful for a backup drive as you only have to connect one wire when using it and otherwise the enclosure and the contained disk would have no electrical connection to anything which protects it against destructions by over-voltage from the electrical grid.

Hey Robert, welcome to Hardware Recs! While I'm not aware of any such commercial product, if you're electrically inclined, this is the sort of thing that you could design yourself. Most HDDs require both 12V and 5V, the former of which is not typically supplied by most USB-PD compliant chargers, and AFAIK, is not supplied by and USB-PD compliant host devices. You could absolutely do a little voltage conversion from 20V though and make it work.

However, if your end goal is simply a one-wire backup disk, I would encourage you to look at SSDs (if your budget allows for it.) Compatibility will be substantially better and simpler, with much lower power draw, and the cost of large SSDs has decreased immensely.

@JMY1000 SSDs are still too expensive. As backup disk I use 6-10TB disks. In addition SSDs are not recommended for backup (long term storage) as the flash cells should better be checked regularly if they have lost their charge partially. And e.g. my off-site backup disk is only used once a year, so an SSD would be cost inefficient and not safe.

If you’re using multiple disks, you might want to consider DAS? You’ll need to power it separately, but it’d prevent you from having to swap out disks. HDDs are also not recommended for non-redundant cold storage, as they’re also subject to bit rot; if you need true cold storage, your best options are optical or tape.

@JMY1000 As I wrote SSDs are too expensive and you propose tape storage where the base device without an tape costs more than an expensive consumer SSD. I have posted my question, it is technically feasible, the most cost effective way for private end users and I am not interested  in other ways.

Related Question: https://superuser.com/questions/1658462/can-a-3-5-hard-drive-use-usb-c-as-its-only-power-input

@Robert You're welcome to use HDDs for cold storage, but you need to be aware that without multiple redundancy they are not a safe solution: they are subject to bit rot and the data will eventually become unrecoverable without redundancy or regular refreshing. If that's okay for your use case, that's great, but if not, be aware that you are risking losing your data; otherwise, you should seek an alternative (e.g. optical media, which doesn't have the same upfront costs as tapes.) My goal is to help you; I just want to make sure you have all the information and options available.

Unfortunately with hardware recs the answer is sometimes "that doesn't exist", even if it is technically feasible. AFAIK, no one currently manufactures what you want. If you want it, you can design and build it (and maybe even share or sell it!) Often though, the reason a commercial product doesn't exist is because the niche is extremely small: in this case, that's probably because very few USB hosts have PD out, and none have 12V PD out AFAIK. Thus, most hosts would require a separate power supply anyway. Aside: if you tell us what computer you're using, we can check what it supports.
